# "was insisting that he come visit" or "was insisting that he should come visit"

Tags: american-english, british-english, subjunctives

Am I constructing the subjunctive correctly in this sentence:

> Mary explained that Sarah **was insisting that her son Rino come visit** his father at New York.

Or should I write this instead:

> Mary explained that Sarah **was insisting that her son Rino should come visit** his father at New York.

Comment: Your first example is pure subjunctive.

Comment: @RolaAbu-Ghazaleh:  Your sentence is ungrammatical, quite apart from the fact that it displays no use of the subjunctive mood.

Comment: By the way, it should be "**in** New York" - we generally don't use *at* with city names.

Comment: Does the word "come" add anything to these sentences?  I would be much more likely to omit it and just say "visit" or "should visit".  If I did include it, I would say "come and" rather than "come" - but I think that's because "come" + *infinitive* is AmE ( http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/and ).  BrE uses the *and*.

Comment: In BrE we can use *at* + city name, but it has a different meaning. "At Oxford" or "at Edinburgh" often means "at Oxford University", etc.  In other cases, "at Oxford" might be shorthand for "at Oxford station" or at some other specific place.  "Get off the train at Crewe", "change at Derby", etc.

Comment: @rjpond:   I don't think the dictionary is saying that AmE speakers don't use **and** there (come see vs come and see), but that we often drop it. In the part of Pennsylvania where I live, native speakers (myself included) say "come and {verb}" quite a lot, and it is not "formal" in any way. If anything, the **and** version seems to be in a more informal register.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I didn't say that AmE speakers couldn't use the "and" there, but thanks for the clarification.  I didn't say that the "and" version was formal.  In BrE, it is somewhat informal, too, although the "and"-less version is possibly considered slightly more informal (perhaps because of its Americanness or perhaps because it involves omitting a word).  The more formal equivalent would be "come to visit", I suppose, though I am not certain if it means exactly the same.

Comment: @rjpond: Not you. The *dictionary* you cited calls the American dropping of the "and" informal (*come see* vs *come and see*).

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: It actually describes both versions as informal.  "In informal speaking we often use *and* after *go* and *come*."

Comment: @rjpond: You're right.  However this isn't "informal" but deictic.  The **go** and **come** add the speaker's perspective on the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is indeed in the subjunctive mood. I'm not sure if the second one would still be considered subjunctive, but nevertheless, it is perfectly acceptable.

Well, except for one thing. We wouldn't say "at New York", we would say "**in** New York".

Comment: There's also the question of whether Sarah lives in New York.  If she does, "come visit" seems correct; if she doesn't, I think "go visit" would be more idiomatic.

Comment: You are correct. "Come" implies that she does indeed live in New York.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, "Mary explained that Sarah was insisting that her son, Rino, *come visit* his father [in] New York."  However, I would write, "Mary explained that Sarah was insisting that her son, Rino, come to visit his father in New York."  I might also drop the "come to" and just say or write, "that her son, Rino, visit his father in New York" because this is more formal than "come visit".  "Come visit" is an informal way of saying it in English, usually American English; it should be "come to visit" because it needs the infinitive form after "come" rather than the bare infinitive.  This isn't always the case as some verbs take bare infinitives directly after them.  In this situation, however, it's more informal than anything else.  People like faster ways to say things in any language and no one wants to say adscititious words like "to" there when they lack substance and are merely relational in context. Here, the word "to" would be a function word rather than a content word.  Function words have little semantic content of their own and simply indicate a grammatical relationship.

Also, it probably should be "go" instead of "come" unless Mary lived in New York and were asking her daughter to come to New York to visit her father.  Otherwise, it would be "go visit" or "go to visit".